# How to access serialized user with Passport in node.js

Tags: node.js, session, passport.js

I've been able to authenticate with Passport but I don't know how to access to the serialized user. I have read in several places that the way to access it is with req.user but when I try it with a GET to /hello, it says that user is undefined...

Here is my app.js

```
var express = require('express');
var routes = require('./routes');
var user = require('./routes/user');
var authentication = require('./routes/authentication');
var content = require('./routes/content');
var posts = require('./routes/post.js');
var upload = require('./routes/upload.js');
var media = require('./routes/media.js');
var http = require('http');
var path = require('path');
var passport = require('passport');
var LocalStrategy = require('passport-local').Strategy;
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var mongoConnectionString = 'mongodb://localhost/judgmental';
var User = require('./models/user.js');

mongoose.connect(mongoConnectionString, function(error) {
    if (error) {
        throw error;
    }
    console.log('Successfully connected to MongoDB');
});

var app = express();

// all environments
app.set('port', process.env.PORT || 3001);
app.set('views', __dirname + '/views');
app.set('view engine', 'jade');
app.set('upload_dir', __dirname + '/uploads/posts/');
app.use(express.favicon());
app.use(express.logger('dev'));
app.use(express.bodyParser({uploadDir:'./uploads/temp'}));
app.use(express.methodOverride());
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));
app.use(express.cookieParser('keyboard cat'));
app.use(express.cookieSession({secret:'keyboard cat', maxAge: 1000}));
app.use(express.session({ secret: 'keyboard cat' }));
app.use(passport.initialize());
app.use(passport.session());
app.use(app.router);

// development only
if ('development' == app.get('env')) {
    app.use(express.errorHandler());
}

passport.use(new LocalStrategy(
    function(username, password, done) {
        var query = username.indexOf("@") !== -1 ? {email: username} : {username: username};
        User.findOne(query, function (err, user) {
            if (err) { return done(err); }
            if (!user) { return done(null, false, { message: 'Incorrect username.' }); }
            user.authenticate(password, function(error, user){
                if (error) { return done(error); }
                if (!user) { return done(null, false, { message: 'Incorrect password.' }); }
                return done(null, user);
            });
        });
    }
));

// routes
// Users
app.get('/', routes.index);
app.get('/users', user.list);

app.get('/content', content.show);

// Posts
app.get('/post', posts.single);
app.get('/post/test/:id', posts.test);
app.get('/posts', posts.list);
app.post('/post/submitPost', posts.submitPost);
app.get('/post/upload', posts.uploadDefault)

// Upload
app.post('/upload/upload-file', upload.upload);

// Image handler
app.get('/media/:id', media.getImage);

// Authentication
app.post('/signUp', authentication.signUp);
app.post('/signIn', authentication.signIn);
app.get('/hello', function(req, res) {
    res.render('index.jade', { id: req.user.id });
});

passport.serializeUser(function(user, done) {
    console.log("serializeUser");
    done(null, user.id);
});

passport.deserializeUser(function(id, done) {
    console.log("deserializeUser");
    User.findById(id, function(err, user) {
        done(err, user);
    });
});

http.createServer(app).listen(app.get('port'), function(){
  console.log('Express server listening on port ' + app.get('port'));
});
```

I know that the user is serialized because the console logs "serializeUser" when I authenticate. Does someone knows how to get the serialized user in my GET /hello?

Comment: You code looks ok to me. Does POST /signIn works ? Do you see you session cookie in your browser after signing in ?

Comment: Yes the POST is working, I do the authentication and then send back an answer that is received on the client side. There is also a cookie called "connect.sess" that is updated, but its content is weird (s%3Aj%3A%7B%22passport%22%3A%7B%22user%22%3A%22527fec0ba5ca2d941f000001%22%7D%7D.T5YD0bo4AtV%2Fh3a0Z5TixOie5XKOZcy7fiD3in2MuPM)...

Comment: Probably need to see your authentication route to understand what the signIn function is doing to move forward.

Comment: Actually, playing around with my code, I think this might be a quirk/bug of Passport or express.  I use express.session() rather than cookieSession, along with RedisStore to store the session, and it works fine.  From experimenting, it looks like the problem is more in the deserializeUser function, which doesn't seem to be finding the user based on the cookie (suggesting that Passport or Express are generating a malformed cookie maybe?)

Comment: I also use `express.session` right after the `cookieSession`. The deserializeUser function can't be the problem, it is never called... Maybe this is the problem (I don't quite know what the deserialize function do and when it should be called)... And is the RedisStore required to store the session?

Comment: I decided to forget about Passport, this shit is way too complicated for no reason. Just using plain express is way more easier. Check out this small tutorial about how to use sessions : http://blog.modulus.io/nodejs-and-express-sessions

Answer (score 0):

IIRC there can be a problem if the session storing middleware is applied out of order. Check out the passportjs express3 example [here](https://github.com/jaredhanson/passport-local/blob/master/examples/express3/app.js)

Comment: Link is broken... Next time when you post a link in your answer please include the actual text summary so it won't break and turn useless in the future.